# nodejs http post request using "got" library does not deliver its req.body

Tags: node.js, express, http, post

Having this:

```
const Got = require("got");
const getStream = require("get-stream");

//SERVER
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/route", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("at route");
  res.end();
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening on port 3000");
});

//CLIENT
let gotOptions = {
  method: "post",
  // I want this to be consoled out
  body: "param1=abc&param2=def&param3=geh"
};

const url = "http://localhost:3000/route";
let response = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  //client request
  let stream = Got.stream(url, gotOptions);

  stream.on("response", async res => {
    resolve(await getStream(res));
  });
});
response.then(data => console.log(data));
```

output:

```
listening on port 3000
{}
```

the same undefined would be if I separated the express part in another file and started it. And after started only the client part. Still undefined. So how to see the `req.body` at server?

Comment: Do you have a bodyparser middleware?

Comment: `app.post('/route's, (req, res) => ..` is missing a body parser middleware. For instance [`express.json`](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html)

Comment: @Evert even with these middlewares, I got empty object

Comment: @derpirscher even with these middlewares, I got empty object

Comment: You have not set the Content-type header -- `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @slebetman why would that matter? Now the server part works correctly though (it consoles the incoming body). But the client part does not. After it the server consoles out the body a responses back with `res.send("at route")`, the client never consoles that out and instead hangs as if `await getStream(res)` never resolves. How to solve that?

Comment: @milanHrabos at least try to catch errors! Also do you need the streams API, the promise api seems simpler to use.